# How do I prove that $x,y$ and $z$ lie on the same line if they are related to the same parameter?

Tags: parametric

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032960/how-to-prove-that-the-intersection-of-two-planes-is-a-line-using-parameteric-eq/4032984?noredirect=1#comment8327363_4032984)

How exactly does that work? I would be grateful for a proof but barring that just the name of the theorem, so I can look it up myself.

My work/thoughts so far:

---

If we start with a system like the one below:

$$y+az=b$$
$$x+fz=g$$

I guess I could solve both sides for z and get something like:

$$z=\frac{b-y}{a}$$
$$z=\frac{g-x}{f}$$

Which I guess implies that:
$$\frac{b-y}{a}=\frac{g-x}{f} $$
$$y=\frac{a(g-x)}{f}+b $$

Which is really just another way of writing $y=kx+m$, so for every value of z, the relationship between x and y can be written as a line. Since there is an infinite number of z, that means we can vizualize all the possible lines as an infinite plane.

If we could define a vectpr z we could restrict the possible solutions to the values in the plane that satisfiy both $y=\frac{a(g-x)}{f}+b $ and the equation for z. It just so happens we have two expressions for z, $z=\frac{b-y}{a}$ and $z=\frac{g-x}{f}$.

I dont' know, where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

I’m awfully sorry, but your question is imprecise, especially since I don’t see mention of any parameter anywhere in the title or body. So my attempt at an answer may not satisfy you at all. Nonetheless:

It seems to me that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are to be the coordinates of points in $3$-space $\Bbb R^3$. And that $a$, $b$, $f$, and $g$ are parameters which define the problem. You pretty clearly are of the same opinion.

Furthermore, you have correctly solved for $z$ in the two cases, $z=-\frac1ay+\frac ba$, $z=-\frac1fx+\frac gf\,$. These say, separately, that a choice of $x$ and $y$ gives you $z$. *But not necessarily the same* $z$ in the two cases.
For instance, say $x=1$ and $y=2$. Then you get, in the first case, the point $(1,2,-\frac2a+\frac ba$) and in the second case $(1,2,\frac1f+\frac gf)$. As you see, the $z$-values need not be the same.

There’s where you went wrong, when you said, “Which I guess implies that…”

You want to think of the situation geometrically, where the first equation defines a particular plane in space (depending on the values of $a$ and $b$), and the second equation defines some other plane in space. (They will not be parallel planes in this case, because in the two cases, the vectors perpendicular are $(0,1,a)$ and $(1,0,f)$, definitely not parallel.) Since the planes are not parallel, they have a line in common. (If your geometric intuition is still in its infancy, think of the east wall of your room and the south wall, which intersect in a vertical *line*, namely the SE seam between the two walls.)

If you want a parametric representation of this line, the work is done for you. You have the three parametric formulas, in terms of a parameter $t$:

\begin{align}
x&=g-ft\\
y&=b-at\\
z&=t
\end{align}

Comment: If you follow the link you will find that I started by trying to find a formula for the intersection two planes, and that's how I ended up with those expressions. Since it's a system of equation (I just don't know how to create that left-sided bracket) that must mean that x, y and z must have the same value in both expressions, correct?

Comment: And if x, y and z in both expressions that would mean I could eliminate z from the equation and write x and y in terms of each other and the various constants, forming the equation of a line. Is that correct?

Comment: Not correct. A single linear equation among the three variables will *never* define a line. Usually define a plane. Your mistake is unchanged, namely to think that the “$z$” in the two equations is the same number. Not usually the case.